# Unity track object position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, object, transform

I'm trying to make a cube to stay on a moving object. I want to track the object's position. How can I do that? I have searched for answers on unity's website. I did not find any answer/ that worked for me.

Is it okay to move my cube to the object's position with a transform? (`transform.position = new Vector3(object.position.x, transform.position.y, object.position.z)`) ? Or there is a better way to move my cube to the position of the object?

Comment: Does your cube have a Rigidbody Component? If your cube is moving with physics the answer will be different.

Comment: My cube has rigidbody. Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make collider on your moving object,then when it touches this object,set transform.position=movingObject.transform.position
You must do it in Update method

Comment: Update or FixedUpdate?

Comment: If you have Rigidbody then use it in fixed update,bcs update depends on free memory of device so it can be slower,and fixed update goes constantly and it is better to use Fixed update if your object is using Phyisics like Rigidbody and etc

Answer (score 0):

If you want your cube to stay on a moving object, you can set the cube's parent as the moving object and the cube's local position will sync with the moving object's transform.

`transform.parent = movingObject.transform`